# Permuting characters in a string

Tags: python, string, permutation

Warning: this question is **not** what you think!

---

Suppose I have a string like this (Python):

```
'[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]]'
```

Now suppose further that I have the permutation of the *characters* `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` which swaps `0` and `1`, as well as (separately) `2` and `3`.  Then I would wish to obtain

```
'[[0, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2]]'
```

from this.  As another example, suppose I want to use the more complicated permutation where `1` goes to `2`, `2` goes to `3`, and `3` goes to `1`?  Then I would desire the output

```
 '[[2, 3], [3, 1], [0, 1]]'
```

**Question**: Given a permutation (encoded however one likes) of characters/integers `0` to `n-1` and a string containing (some of) them, I would like a function which takes such a string and gives the appropriate resulting string where these characters/integers have been permuted - and nothing else.

I have been having a lot of difficult seeing whether there is some obvious use of `re` or even just indexing that will help me, because usually these replacements are sequential, which would obviously be bad in this case.  Any help will be much appreciated, even if it makes me look dumb.

(If someone has an idea for the original list `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]]`, that is fine too, but that is a list of lists and presumably more annoying than a string, and the string would suffice for my purposes.)

Comment: Apologies if I'm just not understanding you, but it's not very clear what you're asking for. If you just want all possible combinations of items, then I would recommend you take it out of the string and flatten the list, then you `itertools` to compute combinations, permutations, or the product of the elements depending on what you actually want. Otherwise, please provide a [mcve] including desired output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Nothing I have tried comes even close, so it's not really trying to resolve a bug.  I am not looking for combinations.  I will attempt to reword it, but I'm not sure how much clearer I can make it ...

Comment: It would help if you were clearer about "Given this input, I would like this/these output(s)"

Comment: That is what I was already asking, but I have now attempted to make it REALLY clear.

Comment: I'm mystified at the down vote.  The answers alone should make it clear this isn't a trivial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think in general you'll need to use a working memory copy of the resultant to avoid the sequential issue you mention. Also converting to some structured data format like an array to work in makes things much easier (you don't say so but your target string is clearly a stringified array so I'm taking that for granted). Here is one idea using eval and numpy:

```
import numpy as np

s =  '[[2, 3], [3, 1], [0, 1]]'
a = np.array(eval(s))
print('before\n', a)
mymap = [1,2,3,0]
a = np.array([mymap[i] for i in a.flatten()]).reshape(a.shape)
print('after\n', a)
```

Gives:

```
before
 [[2 3]
 [3 1]
 [0 1]]
after
 [[3 0]
 [0 2]
 [1 2]]
```

Comment: Yes, I was assuming I'd need to put a copy in somewhere to refer to, which is what I (unsuccessfully) tried.

Comment: I was successful?

Comment: I see.  I think this might work in general - also without numpy, I think, since `flatten` is just a list method, right? (I don't really need the shape that crucially.)  So ... you are just using the list representation of a permutation.  If I try `mymap=[1,0,3,2]` then it should implement my first example, correct?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I do need numpy for `flatten` ... no, never mind, I'm actually using SageMath so [flatten](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/flatten.html) is predefined for nested lists.

Comment: You need the flatten otherwise we'd loop over the three arrays at the top level of nesting not all 6 values. "mymap" is effectively an indexed based look up table that defines a particular permutation. You could also use a dict (hash) which would be a better choice in general - but this is just a quick proof of concept ..

Comment: Yes, agreed, I was just unsure why I needed numpy - and in this case I don't.  It's very convenient for me to get the `mymap` form for permutations in my environment.

Comment: Yeah you don't need numpy just make things easier. For me in my day to day numpy and python pretty come as one :).

Comment: Fair enough!  Same for me and Sage.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution for my particular use case and precomputed stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution using a regular expression with callback:

```
import re

s = '[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]]'

map = [3, 2, 1, 0]

print(re.sub('\d+',                                 # substitute all numbers
             lambda m : str(map[int(m.group(0))]),  # ... with the mapping
             s                                      # ... for string s
            )
)

# output: [[2, 1], [1, 0], [3, 0]]
```

Comment: I think this would work well for someone who understands regex a bit better than I do :) but nice work

Answer (score 1):

```py
permutation = {'0':'1', '1':'0', '2':'3', '3':'2'}
s = '[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]]'
rv = ''

for c in s:
   rv += permutation.get(c, c)

print(rv)
```

?

Comment: Not sure, but would this method work once you hit double digits?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a mapping of your desired transformations:

```
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval('[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]]')
m = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1}
new_d = [[m.get(i) if i in m else 
        (lambda x:i if not x else x[0])([a for a, b in m.items() if b == i]) for i in b] for b in d]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [3, 1], [0, 1]]
```

---

For the first desired swap:

```
m = {0:1, 2:3}
d = ast.literal_eval('[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]]')
new_d = [[m.get(i) if i in m else 
    (lambda x:i if not x else x[0])([a for a, b in m.items() if b == i]) for i in b] for b in d]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely inelegant regarding the quality of this forum I confess but here is my suggestion just to help:

```
string = '[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 3]]'
numbers = dict(zero = 0, one = 1, two = 2, three=3, four = 4, five = 5, six=6, seven=7, height=8, nine = 9)
string = string.replace('0', 'one').replace('1', 'zero').replace('2','three').replace('3', 'two')

for x in numbers.keys():
    string = string.replace(x, str(numbers[x]))
```

> [[0, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2]]

Comment: I like the idea :) but it's unfortunately not realistically implementable in my particular use case

Comment: Wanted to show support :) Perhaps I'll delete this quickly before getting downvoted for `code obsenity` !

Comment: What?  No, it's a reasonable answer, just not "cute".  No deletion necessary.